# seleccionar filas mysql con un rango de fechas que incluya hora (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql

tengo mi base de datos en donde guardo registros pero tengo separada la fecha de la hora
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

quisiera saber como puedo filtrar entre 2 fechas en donde la fecha incluya la hora y los minutos, por ejemplo:

desde 08-06-2022 10:00 hasta 08-06-2022 12:00

de antemano muchas gracias por su ayuda

yo estoy usando esto `BETWEEN '2022-06-08 00:00:00' AND '2022-06-09 23:59:59` pero el problema es que mi base de datos tiene separada la hora y la fecha

Answer (score 1):

Para esos casos no deberías usar BETWEEN sino simples comparadores.

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLA
WHERE FECHA >= '2022-01-01T00:00:00'
   AND FECHA < '2022-01-20T00:00:00' + INTERVAL 1 DAY;
```

Presta atención a que la condición para la fecha inicial es `>=` (Mayor o igual) para que incluya aquellos registros con hora 0.
Mientras que la fecha final se le suma 1 día y el comparador es `<` (Estrictamente Menor). Así se incluyen todos los registros de la fecha final (menores a la hora 0 del día siguiente)

Aquí puedes ver una mejor explicación https://use-the-index-luke.com/es/sql/where/condiciones-complicadas/fechas

Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Podrías concatenar la `fecha` con la `hora`:

```sql
SELECT col1, col2, ..., coln FROM la_tabla
WHERE CONCAT(fecha, ' ', hora)
BETWEEN BETWEEN '2022-06-08 00:00:00' AND '2022-06-09 23:59:59';
```

**[!]** Sin embargo, según [Esta Respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71159650/1545868) (en inglés), posiblemente el método que propongo no es tan eficiente, y podría repercutir negativamente el rendimiento de la BD si hubiesen cientos de miles o millones de registros. Ver la alternativa que, en el mismo post, sugiere el autor.